# what does -x mean in if conditional statement?

Tags: command-line, bash

What does `-x` mean here:

```
if [ -x /etc/rc.local ] then
```

How could I find out this manual page for `if`?

Comment: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html This is page explaining the basics for the bash if.

Comment: It evaluates to true if file exists and is executable.

Comment: Did you try `help if`?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

From the `man bash` pages (especially the CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS section):

```
   -a file
          True if file exists.
   -b file
          True if file exists and is a block special file.
   -c file
          True if file exists and is a character special file.
   -d file
          True if file exists and is a directory.
   -e file
          True if file exists.
   -f file
          True if file exists and is a regular file.
   -g file
          True if file exists and is set-group-id.
   -h file
          True if file exists and is a symbolic link.
   -k file
          True if file exists and its ``sticky'' bit is set.
   -p file
          True if file exists and is a named pipe (FIFO).
   -r file
          True if file exists and is readable.
   -s file
          True if file exists and has a size greater than zero.
   -t fd  True if file descriptor fd is open and refers to a terminal.
   -u file
          True if file exists and its set-user-id bit is set.
   -w file
          True if file exists and is writable.
   -x file
          True if file exists and is executable.

   [...]
```

Comment: It should be noted, executable for a directory means it can be traversed.

Comment: @StevenPenny The second part of the question was "How could I find out this manual page for if?"

Comment: @drewbenn When you invoke `test` in bash, you are not invoking the `test` binary. You are, instead, invoking bash's `test` builtin, which has documentation at `help test`, among other places. `man test` may be misleading in some cases for that reason.

Answer (score 11):

`if` itself is a shell keyword, so you can find information about it with `help if`.  `if` itself only branches based on whether the next command returns true ( 0 ) or false ( not zero ).  What you really want though, is `man [` or `man test`, where `[` is an alias for `test`.  That statement is actually executing `test -x /etc/rc.local`, which tests to see if that file exists and is executable (or has search permission).

Comment: `man [` works too.

Comment: It not only tests to see if it exists, it tests whether the file is executable as well.

Comment: @TomFenech, ahh, right...

Comment: @psusi `if` is not shell builtin it's shell keyword.Run this command `type if` to check for that.

Answer (score 3):

From `info test` :

```
`-x FILE'
    True if FILE exists and execute permission is granted (or search permission, if it is a directory).
```

Execute permission is needed on a directory to be able to cd into it (that is, to make some directory your current working directory).

Execute is needed on a directory to access the "inode" information of the files within.  You need this to search a directory to read the inodes of the files within.  For this reason the execute permission on a directory is often called search permission instead.