# What are the different options (-f, -d, -n) in the IF bash statements?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm looking at the '.profile' file in my home directory and I see different options used with the `IF` statement:

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then...
...
if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then...
...
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then...
...
```

What is the meaning and use of the `-n` `-f` and `-d` options here and generally in other bash scripts?

Comment: I'm sure this has been answered before. You can look at this:[File test operators](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html) and this: [Other Comparison Operators](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html).

Comment: Related [what does -x mean in if conditional statement?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445469/what-does-x-mean-in-if-conditional-statement)

Comment: man test will give you a whole list of file tests, along with the ones you ask about, like -k for testing that a file exists and has the sticky bit set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-f` and `-d` are file test operators options, namely:

`-f` file is a regular file, not a directory

`-d` file is a directory

`-n` is comparison operator option. It returns "true" when the string following the option is `not null`.

Answer (score 5):

All BASH options for if-clauses can be found under the section `CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS` of the documentation (`man bash`).

Quoting it:

> -d file
>
> True if file exists and is a directory.
>
> -f file
>
> True if file exists and is a regular file.
>
> -n string
>
> True if the length of string is non-zero.

Comment: [GNU Bash Reference Manual - Bash Conditional Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html)